# Connecting to SQL database on localhost server.

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I have Apache and SQL running using Xampp and have created a database called "company" in phpMyAdmin. I want to connect to that database using my terminal. I try this, but it fails:

[image]

What is with this error? Am I not using the correct syntax?

Comment: you are alredy in the db Client console.  only try `use company`

Comment: I tried that, it says that "Access is denied for user '@'localhost'' to use database 'company'.

Comment: Than try to logon with root and the Password for root

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify database you want connect to. Try:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
use DBNAME;
```

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Comment: Dude, just from commander, when the app `mysql.exe` is not running yet.

Comment: It is running, otherwise I wouldn't be able to get that error.

Comment: You don't get it. Try these commands: cmd; cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin; mysql -u USERNAME -p; use DBNAME;

Comment: ; is meant like next line

Comment: Oh I see, thanks that worked. So why should it not be running for it all to work?

Comment: Because this is initial connection information, you put into parameter of mysql.exe ...you have to reinit mysql connection otherwise

Comment: If you are done with this question, you can mark it answered :)